# How to align images based on a pixel in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, alignment

I have two similar images: [A] and [B] (please see images). They are offset in X and Y. How to align A over B, using an pixel from A as reference? In other words, locating the indicated pixel from A on B, and make A and B centralized in this pixel.
Thank you.

[image: Image A]
[image: Image B]

Final result make manually

[image]

Comment: These pictures do not look similar; Your central pixel is on the corner of a pentagon in A; there is no matching point in B.

Comment: It looks as though the backbone is similar, follow the horizontal path through each image to find the point the OP wants to detect is the bottom right hand corner of the 6 membered ring. However, I'm not sure an image-processing solution is really the best way forward for this.

Comment: @Prof. Cleiton I'm not sure I understand the question, do you want an algorithm to overlap the images for you?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The images are (chemically) similar.  The right-hand side is the same structure, up to the amide linkages in the center (the `C=O` attached to the `N`s.  The "matching" point is the beginning of the chemical difference, possibly because of a synthetic step.  I suspect that the OP probably wants to align the images for publication.

Comment: @sfstewman: Ok, I see.  Well, I don't think treating these as images is going to be the most effective way of algorithmically "aligning" them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it manually:

```
img1 = 255-mean(imread('a1.png'),3);
img2 = 255-mean(imread('a2.png'),3);

subplot(221);imagesc(img1);axis image
[x1 y1] = ginput(1);
subplot(222);imagesc(img2);axis image
[x2 y2] = ginput(1);



x = x1-x2;
y = y1-y2;

T = maketform('affine',[1 0 x;0 1 y; 0 0 1]');
img2N = imtransform(img2,T,'xdata',[1 size(img1,2)],'ydata',[1 size(img1,1)]);

subplot(2,2,[3 4]);
imagesc(max(img1,img2N));axis image
```

for doing it automaticly, you can do this::

```
%size(img2) <= size(img1)
img1 = 255-mean(imread('a1.png'),3);
img2 = 255-mean(imread('a2.png'),3);
subplot(221);imagesc(img1);axis image
subplot(222);imagesc(img2);axis image
colormap(gray(256))
c = normxcorr2(img2,img1);
[y x] = find(c==max(c(:)));
y = y-size(img2,1);
x = x-size(img2,2);

T = maketform('affine',[1 0 x;0 1 y; 0 0 1]');
img2N = imtransform(img2,T,'xdata',[1 size(img1,2)],'ydata',[1 size(img1,1)]);
subplot(2,2,[3 4]);
imagesc(max(img1,img2N));axis image
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is image registration, which requires, in your case, at least 2 control points, because it's affine transformation without reflect. Given the similarity of those 2 images, I think it's easy to find another referral point. After that you can use `imtransform` or simply `cp2tform` to perform the registration.

Comment: I think what registration does is alignment and overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fine tune the 'XData' and 'YData' properties but you could do this...

```
rgbA = imread('A.jpg'):
rgbB = imread('B.jpg');
alpha(.2)
image(rgbA,'XData',2)
alpha(.2)
hold on
image(rgbB,'XData',2)
alpha(.2)
```